# Eclipse jQuery, Javascript helper plugin?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there such a plugin available for Eclipse? Able to assiste with Javascript programming and click on function to go to function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some plugins, but they're totally buggy. Currently, [Aptana IDE](http://aptana.com/)  supports jQuery, but PDT/ZendStudio does not.

I've created a solution in English language, but it's currently presented on a Russian website. Here's the translation: [jQuery in Eclipse PDT, WTP / Zend Studio for Eclipse](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fblogs%2Fjavascript%2F50831%2F).

---

You can [download the file](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsdoc/downloads/list) from GoogleCode now!

This is jQuery's JSDoc text written by me. Simply add it to Eclipse/JavaScript/User Libraries.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: @kizzx2, here's the new link: http://www.sendspace.com/file/x63fqs . These 'couple of days' are still pending :))

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery there's as far only [jQueryWTP](http://eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-1046.html). According to the status and comments at the linked side I wouldn't expect much from it. It's still in beta and it appears not to work at certain (newer) Eclipse versions.

For normal Javascript coding the builtin Javascript toolkit of Eclipse WTP suffices as far. Are you using "Eclipse for Java EE" which includes the WTP?

Answer (score 1):

Get the Aptana plugin, I've tried most (if not all) of the JS plugins for Eclipse, and the Aptana plugin is head & shoulders above the rest. On the Aptana Studio's download page, simply choose "Eclipse Plugin".

Comment: Did that, and it does nothing. The instructions point you to menu options that don't exist (perhaps previous eclipse versions).

Comment: The download button did nothing, or you installed it and don't see a difference?